# How do I add the correct if value to a csv?

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

```
def main():

    #Open the files we will be using
    inFile = open("names.dat", 'r')
    outFile = open("StudentList.csv", 'w')

    #Process each line of the input file and output to the CSV file 

    for line in inFile:
        data = line.split()
        first = data[0]
        last = data[1]
        idNum = data[3]
        major = data[6]
        year = data[5]

        if data[5] == "Freshman": 
            print("FR")
        elif data[5] == "Sophomore": 
            print("SO")
        elif data[5] == "Junior": 
            print("JR")
        elif data[5] == "Senior": 
            print("SR")
```

And this is the current output

```
Dougherty,Antwan,ADougherty556,Philosophy,Freshman
Knox,Patrick,PKnoxX539,Art,Senior
Parrish,Shane,SParrish474,Gerontology,Sophomore
Kerr,Jerome,JKerrX130,Journalism,Senior
Foley,Adriel,AFoley752,Aviation,Junior
Wagner,Seamus,SWagner837,Electrical,Senior
Hobbs,Ashton,AHobbs844,Urban,Freshman
Petty,Evie,EPetty205,Public,Sophomore
Myers,Leandro,LMyers183,Counseling,Senior
Roberts,Julia,JRoberts830,Library,Freshman
```

Now the question is how do I put the correct value of “FR” instead of Freshman into the csv?

Comment: `if data[5] == "Freshman": data[5] = "FR"`

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python then the main() function to write elements to the outFile could look like this.

```
def main():

    #Open the files we will be using
    inFile = open("names.dat", 'r')
    outFile = open("StudentList.csv", 'w')

    #Process each line of the input file and output to the CSV file 

    for line in inFile:
        data = line.split()
        first = data[0]
        last = data[1]
        idNum = data[2]
        major = data[3]
        year = data[4]
        # You're indexing seems to be off? You have no input example, so I will 
        # assume it's like the output.
        # I suppose you want all the other fields in the same order, just switch Freshman to FR
        outFile.write("{0},{1},{2},{3},".format(first,last,idNum,major))



        if year == "Freshman": 
            outFile.write("FR")
        elif year == "Sophomore": 
            outFile.write("SO")
        elif year == "Junior": 
            outFile.write("JR")
        elif year == "Senior": 
            outFile.write("SR")

        outFile.write("\n")
```